# How to add to a string in For Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm Trying to add to my string in JavaScript and every time it loops through the string appears to stay the same despite the loop working Example:

```
var number = 3

    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var examplestring = "";
        examplestring += "foo ";
    }

output = "foo"



what i want : "foo foo foo "
```

Comment: Move `var examplestring = "";` before the loop. The whole loop body is executed in every iteration. So in your code you are setting `examplestring` to an empty string in every iteration, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: massive oversight , thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set

```
  examplestring = ""
```

inside the loop, so you empty it, then you add `"foo"`, then you empty it, add another foo, empty it add a foo and get only one foo back. You want to declare the variable *outside* off the loop, before the loop runs.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I felt so stupid when i seen this, it wont let me delete now either.

Comment: @aidan no worries :) there are no dumb questions, just dumb answers (except it is something you can google for), and the question will get closed automatically after a while, we got that covered.

Answer (score 0):

Put `var examplestring` outside of loop

```
var number = 3
var examplestring = "";
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {       
    examplestring += "foo ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, you are re initializing `examplestring`. Every time `foo` is assigned to variable `examplestring`. Thats why is is showing `foo` as a result. Declare `examplestring` outside the loop as below:

```js
var number = 3;
var examplestring = "";

for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    examplestring += "foo ";
}

console.log(examplestring);
```